# How to force jersey to accept '>' character in query parameter

Tags: java, encoding, parameters, jersey, query-string

I am facing an issue with Jersey in the client, i have to pass some date filter as parameter, it contains "=>" and Jersey complains :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path segment is null
at com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl.appendPath(UriBuilderImpl.java:547)
```

The query itself is as follow :

```
CustomData dat = getWebResource()
            .path(path)
            .queryParam("display","full")
            .queryParam("date","1")
            .queryParam("filter[date_upd]",">[2016-01-08 10:32:00]")
            .queryParam("filter[valid]","1")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(CustomData.class);
```

After some tries i understood that '>' is the cause of the problem (also space in date is wrongly encoded). If i remove it Jersey is OK but the webservice doesnt work. Is there a special way to pass parameters that have "=>" instead of "="?
When i try the URL directly in a browser it works :

```
http://www.xxxx.com/api/orders/?display=full&date=1&filter[date_upd]=>[2016-01-08%2010:32:00]&filter[valid]=1
```

if i build url with UriBuilder as such :

```
uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://www.xxxx.com/api/"+Order.URLORDER)
                .queryParam("display","full")
                .queryParam("date","1")
                .queryParam("filter[date_upd]",">[2016-01-08 10:32:00]")
                .queryParam("filter[valid]","1").build();            
System.out.println(uri.toASCIIString());
//http://www.xxxx.com/api/orders/?display=full&date=1&filter%5Bdate_upd%5D=%3E%5B2016-01-08+10:32:00%5D&filter%5Bvalid%5D=1
```

And try it in the browser it works too, but if i use the URI in the query then query fails again. The problem should be somewhere else.

```
URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://www.xxxx.com/api/"+Order.URLORDER)
                .queryParam("display","full")
                .queryParam("date","1")
                .queryParam("filter[date_upd]",">[2016-01-08 10:32:00]")
                .queryParam("filter[valid]","1").build();        
CustomData dat = getWebResource().uri(uri).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(CustomData.class);
```

Any idea?

also tried

```
.queryParam("filter[date_upd]",URLEncoder.encode(">[2016-01-08 10:32:00]", "UTF-8"))
```

and

```
.queryParam("filter[date_upd]",URLEncoder.encode("%3E[2016-01-08 10:32:00]", "UTF-8"))
```

With the same "path segment is null" error

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation it turned out the Jersey issue was due to wrong scheme return (because or a parameter), regarding the webservice i finally got it working by replacing the space with a '+' prior to encoding and using UriComponent.encode with UriComponent.Type.FRAGMENT on the parameter containing '>':

```
        CustomData dat = getWebResource()
            .path(path)
            .queryParam("date","1")
            .queryParam("filter[date_upd]",UriComponent.encode(">[2016-01-08+10:32:00]", UriComponent.Type.FRAGMENT))
            .queryParam("filter[valid]","1")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .get(CustomData.class);
```